# Addressing a female child whose name you do not know?

Tags: translation, nuances

I'm writing a piece in which a man tells a girl who he has just rescued from the rubble of a house to follow him. Right now, I just have him saying, “Come,” but I wonder if there's something idiomatic that I can render as English (or even a mix of Japanese and English, like the Japanglish “Smith-*san*.”

*Edited to make this not a translation request*:
I'm thinking he might address her as 妹ちゃん (which I would render as sister-*chan* or little sister) perhaps? Or is there a stand-alone form for ちゃん that he would use?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by something you can “render as English.”

Comment: I'm afraid your question would be off-topic as is. If you're looking for an English phrase, you are on a wrong forum; if you want a Japanese translation, you would need to show your current guess so that the question is not a [translation request](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799).

Comment: @aguijonazo By render as English, I'm writing an English text, so rather than merely a Japanese phrase, I would also need a literal translation to non-idiomatic English,

Comment: 「つれてこい、お嬢ちゃん」

Comment: So you are looking for something idiomatic in Japanese that you can literally translate to non-idiomatic English? I still don't understand. Why don't you just make up non-idiomatic English? 妹ちゃん is non-idiomatic in Japanese but I don't see why "sister-chan" doesn't work for you and your readers, who anyway don't understand Japanese but might recognize "chan" as Japanese.

Comment: @aguijonazo Exactly.

Comment: @JimmyYang 「つれてこい」 means "Bring (someone) along", "Bring (someone) here". I guess you meant 「つ**い**てこい」 instead. (ついておいで would fit better with the softness of 「お嬢ちゃん」, though.)

Comment: Hmmm is the piece you are writing in English? are the characters Japanese or is the scene set in Japan? What is the need for introducing Japanese idiomatic expressions if you are not writing it in Japanese?; TLDR, why don't you just use "little girl" or such?